# URL in .gitmodules versus URL in .git/modules/<module-name>/config

Tags: git

I may have messed something up in a git repo containing submodules. So, assuming the submodule name is 'xxx' there is a difference in the URL noted for the 'xxx' module in file:

```
./gitmodules
```

… and the URL noted in file:

```
./git/modules/xxx/config
```

(under the `remote "origin"` section)

My questions are:

1. am I correct that this is erroneous?
2. how do I reconcile the two? The correct one is that found in file `.gitmodules`
3. why was this redundancy allowed in the first place in the architecture of git?
4. is there a bash / git way to check that there is no other inconsistency (I have many submodules and this problem may occur elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. am I correct that this is erroneous?

It could be. Or it could be a discrepancy created by a `.gitmodules` updated and pulled. Or it could be a deliberate decision of the local user to connect a submodule to a different copy of the submodule.

> 2. how do I reconcile the two?

```
cd xxx # into the submodule
git remote set-url origin <correct-URL>
```

or

```
git submodule sync xxx
```

> 3. why was this redundancy allowed in the first place in the architecture of git?

Security measure so that a file (`.gitmodules`) committed and pushed to the superproject wouldn't impose and changes in the local configs. Local configs are owned by the local user, the remote repository must not change anything in it until the local user inspects the changes and agrees. Also it allows the local user to have her own configs and URLs if she wishes so for whatever reason.

> 4. is there a bash / git way to check that there is no other inconsistency…

Check — no; you could write your own scripts. There is is a way to sync URLs without checking:

```
git submodule sync --recursive
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-sync--recursive--ltpathgt82308203).